# Mysql database replicate with failure alarm

Tags: mysql

I have a Main (master) database that filled up every 2 hour with about 2mil record(different table).
now i want to impelement some fail-safe method to have another db in case of first goes down.
as i googled i find these solution :
make trigger on first db , make replication and make 3rd (php-python) system to do fetch and insert into slave db.
now what is the best way to do this and have some logs reports in case of something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think replication will do the trick. I don't really get why do you need 3rd one, but if you really want, you can make as much slaves as you want.

As far as notifications go, you can use some homebrew script based on `SHOW STATUS` or comparing master and slave metadata, for example. Or you can use some toolkits like [Percona](http://www.percona.com/) or [MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog).